# Updating "expires" with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and mongoose, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to do the following.
I have a Schema, say "User", which includes a field like this:

```
createdAt  : {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: '4h'}
```

Therefore, when I create a new user, say `var user=new User()` (assume User `requires` the correct model), the new user created will be deleted after (approximately) 4h (if I understood it correctly).

I was wondering if there is a way to update the `expires` property of a user. I would like to do the following:

- Retrieve the user from my database
- Update `expires`, such that the user does NOT expire anymore
- Save the changes

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do that is to set the value to `null`. You'd lose your `createdAt` value, which you might not want so what I'd personally do is this:

1. Remove the `expires` index on the existing field.
2. Create a field named `expires` or `deletionDate` with the 4 hour time to live.
3. If the user should not be deleted, set the value to `null`.

I personally prefer to set the `ttl` to 0 and set the date to `{default: function() { return new Date(Date.now()+1000*60*number_of_hours); }`. That would make it easier to arbitrarily extend the time to live of a document and it's easier to read in the db.

Comment: I do not see why the index should be removed - for any document not containing the indexed field it evaluates to `null` anyway.

Comment: I'm assuming that he wants to keep the `createdAt` field and its value forever. If you set the `createdAt` to `NULL` the document wouldn't be removed, sure, but then you'd have to rely on the `ObjectId` to see when a document was created. Having a separate field for `createdAt` and one for `expires` solves the problem in a nicer way.

Comment: So you meant to remove the ttl index on the `expires` field. This wasn't clear in your post.

Comment: Uh, no. In the OP's post, there's currently only a `createdAt` field, with an `expires/ ttl index`. This index should be removed. Then, a _new field_ named `expires` can be added with an `expires/ ttl index` on it. This way, he has a nullable field (the new one) whose value can be removed while not losing the creation timestamp (the existing field), which he'll undoubtedly wants to keep.

Comment: Small typo? It should be 1000 * 60 * 60 * number_of_hours